# Verilog DFF Simulation Producing x for Output

Tags: verilog, flip-flop

This should be the simplest issue to sort out but for some reason I just can't figure it out. I'm currently teaching myself Verilog and as an exercise have been developing very basic modules and test benches for these modules. One of these modules is the D Flip Flop (DFF). Here is the DFF module (no reset):

```
module DFF( clk, D, Q );
    parameter n = 1;    // DFF width
    input clk;
    input [n-1:0]  D;
    output [n-1:0] Q;
    reg [n-1:0] Q;

    always @( posedge clk ) begin
        Q <= D;
    end
endmodule
```

And here is the test bench:

```
module DFF_tb;
    reg clk, D;
    reg Q;

    DFF #(1) DUT ( clk, D, Q );

    initial begin
        clk = 1'b0;
        forever #10 clk = ~clk;     // Generate clock
    end

    initial begin   
        D = 0;                          // Check D = 0
        if ( Q !== 0 ) $display( "[FAIL] Q = 0" );

        #40 D = 1;                      // Check D = 1
        #40
        if ( Q !== 1 ) $display( "[FAIL] Q = 1" );

        $finish;                            // Complete test
    end
endmodule
```

And here is the simulation:
[image]

The test bench reg Q stays x for the duration of the simulation (thought Q[0] doesn't...).

Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reset your flop, therefore before the first clock edge, Q does not have any known value.

Usually a flop has an async reset, which should be asserted at the beginning of the simulation in your test bench. The always block in your FF should be:

```
always @( posedge clk or posedge reset ) begin
  if (reset)
     Q <= '0;
  else
     Q <= D;
end
```

Also, you don't need to define Q as a reg. It can be a wire. Working code on [edaplayground.com](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/jY)

Comment: So this is something I probably still need to learn about FPGAs but why when D is set is Q not set, regardless of Q's value at the first clock edge? Shouldn't Q be set to a know value, D?

Comment: @nslogan: When D changes, Q will not change until the next posedge of the clock at which D is sampled. In your testbench D is modified exactly at the posedge of the clock, which is not sampled until the next clock edge. Notice that in real hardware, you want D to be stable around the clock edge. You can mimic this in the testbench by delaying the assignment to D a bit more, for example, you can change the first #40 to #45.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to even check for stability around the clock edge, that's exactly what it was. I modified my delay so that D was stable and everything worked properly. Thanks!